# facebook sdk replacement : ios

Tags: ios, facebook-ios-sdk

I wanted to replace **FacebookSDK.framework** to newer one i.e, **v3.23**. I downloaded it from Facebook developer site and then checked for version in their sample application using `[FBSetting SDKVersion]` method. It said 3.23.1. Same SDK I replaced it to my app by deleting previous one and adding new **FacebookSDK.framework**. I cleaned it and executed which shows `[FBSetting SDKVersion`] as v3.13. How is this happening ? Where could I be wrong?

Comment: in any time if u use any third party in your project use **pods** -- it taken the automatic updates from SDK

Comment: I didnt get your point! @Anbu.Karthik

Comment: if u r using pods in your projects the  third party files automatically updated , no need to install/replace the new SDKs

Comment: Any other solution apart from using pods?? Wanted to know how I wrong here?